# My website domain keeps switching hosting ip address

Tags: azure, dns, hosting, namecheap

I had bought my domain name through namecheap. Recently I set up MS Azure and created a VM machine which runs apache and wordpress. The VM has an IP address which is pointing to my domain name. A few days ago I removed namecheap hosting and transferred everything to azure. BUT for some reason, my domain quantiv3.com keeps switching from the old namecheap IP address to the new azure IP address. This can be seen when doing a DNS look up on mxtoolbox.com... I can't figure out what i'm doing wrong. Could anyone help? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 8 Name Servers listed for your domain.

4 are reporting one IP address and the other 4 are reporting another IP address.

The solution is to first correctly configure the correct DNS servers at your Domain Registrar. Then correctly configure the correct DNS servers pointed to by the Name Servers.

Typically you only configure one set of Name Servers. For your domain you have two sets of Name Servers. The first is provided by Microsoft Online (Office 365) and the second is provided by Azure DNS. Pick one or the other and correctly configure your DNS Registrar. If you decide to keep both sets, then you must configure both sets to be identical except for the SOA record.

Comment: Oh I see!! The Azure DNS is the one with the correct IP address (51.124.142.154). I removed the Microsoft Online and now looking mxtoolbox, the IP seems to have stopped changing and is fixed on Azure :) 2 questions though, 1. the Microsoft Online DNS were there due to the fact that I have Outlook e-mail addresses... will e-mail work with these nameservers removed? 2. On GeoPeeper, my site still seems to be alternating IPs in different countries :( Thanks!

Comment: In regards to Outlook, you will need to configure the MX and TXT records on your DNS servers that the Name Servers are pointing to. Duplicate the records that we in the Microsoft Online DNS servers. In regard to GeoPeeper, it takes time for DNS changes to propogate world wide - sometimes 72 hours or even longer.

Comment: Great yes that sorted it! Thanks